# How can I accomplish the removal of comments by another participant, on an answer I had posted, that might be considered derogatory?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

About 24 hours ago, I posted an edit to my answer to a PSE question concerning the time when interstellar travel (in any form, or, at least, without specification of its form) might have begun:  As stated in that edit, it replaced nearly all of the original answer, which had discussed only the time (2017) when the first arrival of an object from interstellar space had been interpreted (by a well-known astronomer appointed by an Ivy League university) as representing the probable arrival of an artifact designed by an alien civilization. My attention had been drawn to my significant error by a downvote and a couple of helpful comments, but some other comments had been absurdly derisive and seem to have had some humorous intent, as they could literally be read as casting aspersions about the astronomer's motivations.

I had deleted most of my own comments, and included, in my edited answer's opening paragraphs, my motivations for the complete revision of my answer:  However, when I added some detail in a new comment on the edited answer a short while ago, I was sorry to see that the entire barrage of comments (minus one or two of my own, which I had been able to delete upon the posting of my answer's edited version) remains visible.

As I believe I'm qualified to access review queues, it may be that I should've deleted the humorous comments when editing my answer, but I'm not sure of the procedure.  In any case, for the moment I'm hoping to have them removed promptly.  Is it necessary to flag a moderator to have that accomplished, or is there a procedure allowing me to accomplish it myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't delete other people's comments directly, in review or otherwise. If you think a comment is rude or abusive, or just no longer needed, you can flag it for moderator attention by clicking the little flag icon next to the comment.

Comment: Is the flag icon visible to the participant who posted the humorous (but possibly objectionable) comments, or to all participants viewing the post until those comments have been removed, or only to me (and the moderators)?

Comment: @Edouard If you flag a post, only you and the moderators will be aware of it.

Comment: Also, can I specify "no longer needed"?

Comment: @Edouard Yes, "no longer needed" is one of the options, and is appropriate if the comments weren't rude but also aren't required any longer. Don't bother on this post- I found it and removed the comments already.